redhat idm delegation to another redhat idm server
I have a requirement about redhat idm managment delegation requirement
situation: we have a redhat idm server in one of our local domain and also have corporate redhat idm server in another domain. I want to authenicate local linux vm located in local domain with corporate redhat idm server. I was exploring the options here and looking for how to delegate the authentication from local redhat idenity server to another redhat idenity server. I could not find ay information how to do this?
Anyone can suggest this how to achieve the above.
Thanks
